# Not able to upload the data on thingworx with api

Tags: python, http, python-requests, thingworx

Tried many ways to upload the data(postman, httpie etc as given on their site) on thingworx but not able to do that.
Please have a look on the following code to upload the data on thingworx:

```
import requests
import json
app_key = 'xxxx'
url = 'http://pp-1804040542ze.devportal.ptc.io/Thingworx/Things/lmtech_thing/Properties/humidity'
prms = {'appKey': app_key}
hdrs = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {'humidiy': '20'}
text = json.dumps(data)
print 'data: ' + text
r = requests.put(url, params=prms, headers=hdrs, data=text)
print r.status_code
```

Have created thing and key successfully. but it always return 404 error.

Tried with postman too. Here are the screenshots as shown below:
[image: GET request is successful]

[image: POST request is giving 404]

[image: Trying to update the property (humidity) value in lmtech_thing]

Comment: Does the application log show anything? The log usually has more detailed error information

Comment: Hello,
Pass appKey as part of the header (add this two rows:
'appKey': 'yourAppKey'
'x-thingworx-session': true

Best Regards

Comment: Please have a look on postman screenshot.

Comment: I believeThingworx cloud platform can be accessed only securely. Did you try out with **https** in the URL?

Comment: Also this will require your request to be signed with a self-signed certificate

Comment: Thanks for support. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me :-)

```
import requests  # Import requests library to send requests to Thingworx

url = 'http://52.199.28.120:8080/Thingworx/Things/work_thing/Properties/temp'
# temp is one of my property name
value = 12    # Upload 12 on Thingworx

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'appkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-thingworx-session': 'true',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

data = {"temp": value}   # JSON data to upload on Thingworx

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data)
# Note that we have to send put request

print 'Response Code:', response.status_code
# If 200 then data has been uploaded successfully
print 'Response Content:', response.content
```